# Passing more information into a Google Maps InfoWindow

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am trying to pass more information into a Google Maps map InfoWindow, but somehow it's not working. It must be just a simple stupid thing but I've spent hours on this and can't find it.

My data is stored as:

```
res[i].id
res[i].name
res[i].date
```

etc.

And then I output it with:

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new

```
google.maps.LatLng(res[i].position.lat,res[i].position.long),
                            title:'',
                            orderid:res[i].id,
                            map:map,
                            icon: icon,
                        });    

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", (function(id) {
    return function() {
    var contentString = '<div><b>Order ID:</b> '+id+'
                         <br><b>Name:</b> '+res[i].name+'</div>'
                         <br><b>Date:</b> '+res[i].date+'</div>';
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
    }
})(res[i].id));
```

The `id` is outputting fine when I use `id` but I don't know how to pass the other variables.. For some reason the name and date always shows `Cannot read property 'XXX' of undefined`

What am I doing wrong? Note there may be many markers on this map, it's in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker,i){
        return function(){
        infoWindow.setContent(infoWindowContent[i]);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        }
})(marker,i));

function getInfoWindowDetails(location){
                            var contentString = '<div id="content" style="width:270px;height:100px">' +
                                                '<h3 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + location.name + '</h3>'+
                                                '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                                                    '<div style="float:left;width:100%">'+ location.status + '</div>'+
                                                '</div>'+
                                            '</div>';
                            return contentString;
                        }
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. get function closure on `res[i]` so you can access its properties in the "click" event handler callback function:

   ```
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", (function(res) {
     return function() {
           var contentString = '<div><b>Order ID:</b> '+res.id+
                    '<br><b>Name:</b> '+res.name+'</div>'+
                    '<br><b>Date:</b> '+res.date+'</div>';
       infowindow.setContent(contentString);
       infowindow.open(map, this);
     }
   })(res[i]));
   ```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hma69mgm/3/)

2. add all the properties you need to use inside the "click" event handler function to the marker and then access them from there (using `this` inside the "click" function to reference the marker).  This has the advantage of allowing the properties to change dynamically (although without doing something to update the `InfoWindow` dynamically, you won't see that until you click on the marker again).  Currently they will always be the first value set (in the response that originally creates the marker).

   ```
   for (var i = 0, len = res.length; i < len; i++) {
     //Do we have this marker already?
     if (markerStore.hasOwnProperty(res[i].id)) {
       markerStore[res[i].id].setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(res[i].position.lat, res[i].position.long));
       markerStore[res[i].id].timeStamp = timeStamp;
       // update its properties from the response
       markerStore[res[i].id].name = res[i].name;
       markerStore[res[i].id].date = res[i].date;
     } else {
       // create one
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker(res[i]);
       marker.setMap(map);
       marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(res[i].position.lat, res[i].position.long));
       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
         var contentString = '<div><b>Order ID:</b> '+this.id+
           '<br><b>Name:</b> '+this.name+'</div>'+
           '<br><b>Date:</b> '+this.date+'</div>';
         infowindow.setContent(contentString);
         infowindow.open(map, this);
       });
       markerStore[res[i].id] = marker;
       markerStore[res[i].id].timeStamp = timeStamp;
     }
   }
   ```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hma69mgm/4/)